# TableModel setCellEditable and automatically setting the value back to false

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm currently trying to implement a JPopupMenu in my JTable that allows the unlocking of a cell for editing using

```
@Override 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getActionCommand() == "Unlock"){
        pTableModel.setCellEditable(this.getSelectedRow(), this.getSelectedColumn(), true);
    }
}
```

This is the related method in the TableModel

```
public void setCellEditable(int row, int col, boolean value) {
    editableCells[row][col] = value;
    this.fireTableCellUpdated(row, col); // I don't think I actually need this 
                                         //because nothing in the cell has changed yet?
}
```

`isCellEditable()` then returns the value of the editableCells[][] array.
but where in my code should I change the cell back to uneditable when focus is lost?

On a slightly related note, I'd also like to have the cell immediately gain focus. I've read about `getEditorComponent().requestFocus()` - but that doesn't seem quite right because nothing is being edited at that time, the cell is only selected (and using that method throws a nullpointerexception which would seem to support my thought process).

Can anyone point me in the right direction please? I can't see where I'm going wrong. Thanks

**Edit: For locking the cell when focus is lost I tried adding a custom cellrenderer with a focusListener:

```
private class CustomCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{
    public CustomCellRenderer(){
        addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                pTableModel.setCellEditable(getSelectedRow(), getSelectedColumn(), false);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

but that hasn't seemed to work either, but I'm probably implementing it incorrectly (although I've checked that the renderer has been added)

---

SSCCE

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class CellTest {    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
    private static void createAndShowGUI(){
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();

        f.add(panel);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}


class MyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    private JTable table;
    private MyTableModel model;
    private JScrollPane sp;
    private List<Person> people;

    MyPanel(){
        people = new ArrayList<>();
        people.add(new Person("Will", 1));
        model = new MyTableModel(people);

        table = new JTable(model);
        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                maybeShowPopup(e);
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
                maybeShowPopup(e);
            }
        });

        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        sp = new JScrollPane(table);  
        this.add(sp);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Unlock")) {
                model.setCellEditable(table.getSelectedRow(),table.getSelectedColumn(),true);   
        }
    }

    private JPopupMenu createPopupMenu(){
        JPopupMenu pop = new JPopupMenu();
        JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("Unlock");
        item.addActionListener(this);
        pop.add(item);
        return pop;
    }

    private void maybeShowPopup(MouseEvent e){
        int currentRow = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
        if(currentRow >= 0 && currentRow < table.getRowCount())
            table.setRowSelectionInterval(currentRow, currentRow);
        else
            table.clearSelection();

        if(table.getSelectedRow() < 0) return;
        if(e.isPopupTrigger() && e.getComponent() instanceof JTable){
            JPopupMenu pop = createPopupMenu();
            pop.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
    }
}
```

And the TableModel and data class:

```
class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{
    private List<Person> data;  
    private String[] colNames = new String[]{"Name","Age"};
    private boolean[][] editableCells;

    public MyTableModel(List<Person> data){
        this.data = data;
        this.editableCells = new boolean[this.getRowCount()][this.getColumnCount()];
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() { return data.size(); }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() { return colNames.length; }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col){
        Person p = data.get(row);
        switch(col){
            case 0 : return p.getName();
            case 1 : return p.getAge();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col){
        return editableCells[row][col];
    }

    public void setCellEditable(int row, int col, boolean value){
        editableCells[row][col] = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col){
        Person p = data.get(row);
        switch(col){
            case 0 : p.setName((String)value);break;
            case 1 : p.setAge((int)value);break;
        }
        this.setCellEditable(row, col, false);
        this.fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }

    public void setData(List<Person> data){
        this.data = data;
        this.fireTableDataChanged();
    }
}

class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void setName(String name){ this.name = name;}
    public String getName(){ return name; }
    public void setAge(int age){ this.age = age;}
    public int getAge(){ return age; }
}
```

Apologies for the length - I didn't know how to make it shorter without perhaps poorly recreating what I wanted to achieve. There's a mistake in this code in that to right click and 'Unlock' you have to have already left-clicked a row otherwise they'll be an arrayIndexOutOfBounds exception. I haven't been able to find the exact cause yet.

But basically when you right-click and then select unlock, I'd like the cursor to appear in the cell. At the moment you click unlock and then have to double click the cell.

Comment: A renderer is not a real component. It is just used to paint an image of a component. It will never get focus. Don't use "==" to compares Strings. Use the `equals(...)` method. Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Sorry it's not so minimal, but I've posted a fully working example with a description of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but where in my code should I change the cell back to uneditable when focus is lost? -

You could:

1. override the `setValueAt(...)` method of your TableModel to make a cell uneditable once the data is changed.
2. use a `TableModelListener` It will generate an event when the data of a cell is updated.

Comment: thanks. putting it in setValueAt() works perfectly, much appreciated. setCellEditable() calls fireTableCellUpdated() though, so I don't think I can put it in there without an infinite loop, but I understand that without an SSCCE you probably can't comment. eitherway it's now working, so thanks again.

Comment: just before I mark this answered - any ideas on how should I approach making the cell editable immediately? ie I right-click the cell, select 'unlock', and the cursor is there. rather than having to then double-click again afterwards. I can make an SSCCE if that helps, but even if you just have a vague direction to point me in it would help.

Comment: @NickW, `setCellEditable() calls fireTableCellUpdated() though` - it shouldn't invoke any fireXXX(), method since the data in the cell didn't change.

Comment: yeah, ignore that, I've just realised that was an entirely different bug I fixed about an hour ago.

Comment: @NickW, This question has been answered. If you have another question then ask a new question and post a proper [mcve]. Your question is about putting a cell into edit mode on an Action. So none of your custom code is needed. All you need is a JTable with a DefaultTableModel. Then you add a JButton with an ActionListener. When you click on the button you place the currently selected cell in edit mode. Once you understand the concept of how to do this, THEN you apply to knowledge to your real application. We are not going to look at all the code that is not relevant to the concept.

Comment: sorry, i just didn't know how to explain the concept.